# How can i send a body and not only a status - .NET Core API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I have a Middleware in my .Net Core API (some code below). The Middleware works fine. But I would like to send more information than just the status. But how?
context.Response.Body is an IO.Stream (i don't like streams)

```
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
public AuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
   _next = next;
}
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
  if(/*false*/){
      await _next.Invoke(context);
  }else{
      context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
      context.Response.Body = ??????
      return; 
  }
}
```

code snippet from [ASP.NET Core Web API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977088/asp-net-core-web-api-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You can send any data by converting a object in json and then convert json to string.

With string, you can create steam. Below is the sample code to create stream from a string.

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("i am sample string");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray );
```

Now you can assign this steam to body

```
context.Response.Body = stream;
```

Comment: This did not work for me. @Kirk Larkin found my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304972/asp-net-core-2-0-how-to-return-custom-json-or-xml-response-from-middleware?rq=1